# In Mean.IO how can use dependencies injection into server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, server-side, mean.io

To explain my question, take look to this example project's structure:

- ..
- packages/custom

  - module1

    - ...
    - server

      - models

        - utils.js
  - module2

    - ...
    - server

      - models

        - my.js

I want to use **utils.js** inside **my.js** like that:

```
var utils = require('utils');
```

I try different approachs but have the same result:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'utils'
...
```

The only mode that I found is to use relative path but I think is not the best method.

In the MEAN.io documentation, it's no clear how to use the dependency injection on the server-side (the client-side works very well) outside *app.js*.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For do that, you must load the module putting it into "node_modules" directory in the root. You should review how it works in this link:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

```
- app
   - node_modules
      - utils
         - index.js (Rename utils.js or create a package.json file)
   - packages
      - custom
         - module2
            - server
               - models
                  - my.js
```

So you can use this line into my.js

```
var utils = require('utils');
```

But you can do this:

```
- app
   - packages
      - custom
         - module2
            - server
               - models
                  - my.js
         - utils
            - index.js
```

Then you must do this into my.js

```
var utils = require('../../../utils');
```